# ASP.NET Remote debug

Tags: asp.net, debugging, debug-symbols

I have stumbled on stupid situation with ASP.NET web application remote debug. I'm trying to describe the situation.

I have an ASP.NET application deployed on remote machine. To debug it, I've run a remote debugging monitor, so I'm able to attach my debugger to the remote process.

All assemblies are compiled in DEBUG mode without any Code Optimization and Debug Info is Full.

All *.pdb files are located with their *.dll in the same folder and all these files are up-to-date.

But when I'm trying to attach my debugger to the remote process, the following message appear: The following module was built either with optimizations enabled or without debug information.

Does anyone have ideas how can I solve aforementioned situation?

Answer (score 1):

Did you set the debug=false attribute in the compilation element in the web.config? I regularly get this error when using the remote debugger, but doing a build first usually makes it work.

Simon

Comment: Yes, I set it to the right option and unfortunately it doesn't help me as well.